# Scanf Confusion

Tags: c, scanf

I observed some strange behavior with scanf() in the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    scanf("\n%d",&n);                       // 1 scanf
    printf("N is entered=%d",n);
    printf("\nAfter n being displayed\n");
    scanf("%d\n",&n);                      // 2 scanf
    prinf("n entered again =%d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

My doubt is with the behavior of the second `scanf()`. The first `scanf()` is moving the cursor to the next line and then takes the input, while in the second `scanf()` takes the input, moves the cursor to the next line and then just waits there until I enter some another integer.

Why does it prompt me to input another integer in the next line, rather than displaying the message n entered in the very next line, even though it is taking the correct value of n?
Below is the output:

```
2 
N is entered=2
After n being displayed
45
543
n entered again=45
```

Comment: @Ayushi Jha If you are going to edit other people's posts, do it for valid reasons. Switching to/from American/Brittish English is not a reason to edit posts, either form is fine. See [what you should have edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29369627/revisions) instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`'\n'` is a whitespace character.

When there is a whitespace character in a `scanf()` format string, it causes `scanf()` to ignore any whitespace characters until it encounters a non-whitespace character  (except when that whitespace is in a `"%[]"` format specifier, as noted by chux in comments).

So, for the input you describe, `scanf()` ignores characters (of which there are none) until the first `'2'`.   The second `scanf()` call reads a second integer, and then tries to ignore whitespace.   So it eats the carriage return, and then keeps going until some non-whitespace character is encountered (the first digit of the third value you enter).   It then waits until the enter key is hit again (which incidentally means dropping subsequent digits of the third value you enter).

That's what is happening, more or less, to cause the behaviour you see.

There is no "moving of the cursor".   `scanf()` interprets characters that are input, and it doesn't perform any output. Moving the cursor to the next line is the result of a output operation (or set of operations), not of an input operation. A `\n` in a format string tells `scanf()` how to interpret and handle input it receives, whereas it tells `printf()` to output a newline. Those are very different operations.

To correct the problem, it would probably be easiest to remove the `'\n'` characters from your format string, because they are not causing the behaviour that you (presumably) expect.

Comment: So \n is treated differently for printf and scanf cause for printf it moves the cursor to the next line rt..?

Comment: scanf() interprets characters that are input.  It doesn't perform output at all.  Moving the cursor to the next line is the result of a output operation (or set of operations), not of an input operation.  A \n in a format string tells scanf() how to interpret and handle input it receives.  A \n in a format string tells printf() to output a newline.   Those are very different operations.

Comment: "when there is a whitespace character in a scanf()...ignore ... any whitespace ..." is true except when that `char` is inside a `"%[]"` specifier.

Comment: True, chux.   I've updated the post to include, as well as expanding on difference between scanf() and printf() in handling format strings.

Answer (score 4):

> The first `scanf()` is moving the cursor to the next line and then takes the input while in the second `scanf()`

That is not necessarily so: `\n` in the first `scanf` takes out any whitepsace preceding the number, not only `\n`. The same thing happens for a space character  and TAB `\t`. Note that the behavior is different from, say, `printf`, which prints whitespace characters as instructed.

Also note that the `\n` in both `scanf`s are unnecessary, because `%d` discards all whitespace preceding the number anyway.

> Why it prompts me to input another integer in the next line rather than displaying the message n entered in the very next line

The prompting is done by `printf` after `\n` is echoed outside `scanf`'s control. When you input an `int`, you enter the digits first, and then you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. All this input is sent back to the console for printing, along with the `\n` character. That is what causes the second prompt to appear on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

`\n` in `scanf` is wrong. Except if you have another field like `scanf( "%d\n%d", &a, &b )`.